# PowerBI Circular Dependencies - Techniques not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, dashboard

I have circular dependency issues that I can't quite seem to resolve even though I'm referring to the article at https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/ for solutions.

**Background on my data model** - 1 data table and a calculated columns data table linked together. I keep them separate for easier reference

**Problem** - I have created a calculated column that I am now referring to in another calculated column in the same table but am getting circular dependency issues

Calculated Column 2 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Calculated Column Table'[Column 1]),ALLEXCEPT('Calculated Column Table','Calculated Column Table'[Primary Key]))

This creates a circular dependency message

**Things I have tried**

VAR1 = 'Calculated Column Table'[Column 1] VAR Result = AVERAGE(VAR 1) RETURN Result

CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Calculated Column Table'[Column 1]'), ALLEXCEPT('Calculated Column Table','Calculated Column Table'[Primary Key]))

CALCULATE(SUM('Calculated Column Table'[Column 1]'), ALLEXCEPT('Calculated Column Table','Calculated Column Table'[Primary Key]))

CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Calculated Column Table'[Column 1]'), ALLEXCEPT('Calculated Column Table'[Column 1]']))What am I getting wrong or is it a limitation?

Comment: Can you replace some the calculated columns/tables with Power Query?

Comment: Unfortunately no access to the data on the Power Query level

Comment: Show your sample data table and the calculated columns you wish to add.